# Removing unneccessary p-tags (Not every p)

Tags: php, functions, tinymce, html, wp-autop

I removed `wpautop` from my theme:

```
function disable_linebreaks($content) {
       remove_filter ('the_content','wpautop');
       return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','disable_linebreaks',1);
```

But now, when switching between HTML and Editor ALL p-tags disappear, even the ones I coded myself.

What I want is just to prevent Wordpress from adding empty `<p></p>` - Code. Basically I'm happy with `wpautop`, it's just that sometimes it's too much (For example around images. There's always an empty p before every image).

Comment: Do you intend to use or not use `wpautop`?

Comment: I dont want to use it. I just want to remove those empty p-tags. I thought disabling autop would do that, but what it does is really too much.

Comment: If someone can tell me a way to remove autop and keep the p-tags, I wrote myself, that would be ok, too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove empty paragraphs from the\_content?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13798/remove-empty-paragraphs-from-the-content)

Answer (score 2):

*If* what you want is really *only*

> to prevent Wordpress from adding empty `<p></p>`

and you'd be happy with removing those after post retrieval from the database, then

```
function wpse108194_remove_empty_paragraphs( $content ) {
   $content = preg_replace( '#<p>\s*</p>#', '', $content );
   return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse108194_remove_empty_paragraphs', 11 );
```

will do.

Comment: I already tried this yesterday. For me it doesn't work (They are still there). Im using the roots theme, it has a lot of functions already built in. Maybe there is a conflict, I don't know. I read, that it does not work for other people, too.

Comment: What does not work for other people? I wrote the above yesterday. That being said, I copied your above function and altered the code - it might be that `1` is too low a [priority](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter#Parameters) and that `wpautop` runs thereafter. Change it to a higher number (as I have now done in the answer) to make it run later.

Comment: preg_replace does not work. I tried it with priority 9999, too. Nothing. There is a similar question, where somebody said, that this did not work. But after that, there where no further responses.

Comment: I will try it again, this evening, with exactly your code. But I dont think, it will work, as I tried it in a few different ways.

Comment: I did find [the question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13798/remove-empty-paragraphs-from-the-content) you are referring to. And from reading that it appears the above *might* indeed not be a solution. *Why* that'd be the case is beyond me - it *should* work, in theory. Now we face another issue though: Your question is an exact duplicate of an existing one. I don't have the time for thorough investigation right now, but this is a topic that *should have a concrete answer* on this site. Might look into it later. Would answer in the existing one, though. This should be closed.

Comment: OK. You are right.

Comment: I just tried the above solution and, off the bat, it didnt work. However, on an off chance, I tried a browser cache refresh and *boom* I got the desired result. I happen to be working locally right now, so maybe that had something to do with the latent effect? Whatever the case, I just wanted to say the solution is indeed working and I couldn't be happier. Seems like this issue will never die, but right now I'm past it B)