# shortcode_unautop shortcode not functioning

Tags: shortcode

I have made my own theme with shortcodes to WordPress.

In my filters I have:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
add_filter('the_content', 'wpautop', 99);
add_filter('the_content', 'shortcode_unautop', 100);
```

This should remove paragraph tags around and in my shortcodes.

My shortcode output (partial of the entire code):

```
$output .= '
    <div ' . implode(' ', $html_attributes) . '>
        <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">
            <div ' . implode(' ', $html_attributes_inner) . '>
                ' . $logo . '

                <div class="button hidden-xs hidden-sm">Læs case</div>

                <div class="content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <h4 class="title">' . get_the_title() . '</h4>

                            <div class="spacer small"></div>

                            <div class="excerpt">' . get_post()->post_excerpt . '</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
';

// Script newlines whitespace, tabs etc.  
return str_replace(["\r", "\n", "\t"], '', '<div class="row cases">' . $output . '</div>');
```

This produces:

```
<div class="row cases">
<div class="col-xs-12"><a href="http://dev.youfront-hosting.dk/case/nori">
<div class="case" style="background-image: url(http://dev.youfront-hosting.dk/content/uploads/nori-restaurant-1120x500.jpg)">
<div class="button hidden-xs hidden-sm">Læs case</div>
<div class="content">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<h4 class="title">Nori</h4>
<div class="spacer small"></div>
<div class="excerpt"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<p></a></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><a href="http://dev.youfront-hosting.dk/case/an-ivy">
<div class="case" style="background-image: url(http://dev.youfront-hosting.dk/content/uploads/anivy-founders-545x500.jpg)"><img src="http://dev.youfront-hosting.dk/content/uploads/anivy-logo.png" alt="">
<div class="button hidden-xs hidden-sm">Læs case</div>
<div class="content">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<h4 class="title">AN-IVY. Nyt gentleman brand med stor passion for fashion, og klassisk herretøj</h4>
<div class="spacer small"></div>
<div class="excerpt">AN-IVY er et brand startet i 2013. De designer herrekollektioner der er inspireret af Ivy Leagues tradioner og moderne fashion. De har en stor passion for mode og klassisk herretøj.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<p></a></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><a href="http://dev.youfront-hosting.dk/case/powderstore">
<div class="case" style="background-image: url(http://dev.youfront-hosting.dk/content/uploads/team-youfront-545x500.jpg)">
<div class="button hidden-xs hidden-sm">Læs case</div>
<div class="content">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<h4 class="title">Powderstore</h4>
<div class="spacer small"></div>
<div class="excerpt"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<p></a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Note the additional `<p>` tags at line 15, 29 and 43.
The paragraph tags disappear if I remove the anchor tag in my shortcode, but that's not a solution I can use.

Comment: Can't you run your shortcode processing filter after the autop processing and not before? Seems like it would save some hassle.

Comment: @majick The theory should work. But shortcode_unautop doesn't seem to function if do_shortcode hasn't been run. (I neither want my shortcodes wrapped in paragraph tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
function wpex_fix_shortcodes($content) {

    return strtr($content, [
        '<p>[' => '[',
        ']</p>' => ']',
        ']<br />' => ']'
    ]);

}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11);

add_filter('the_content', 'wpautop', 100);
add_filter('the_content', 'wpex_fix_shortcodes', 105);
add_filter('the_content' , 'do_shortcode', 110);
```

This runs wpautop before do_shortcode, but removes the paragraph tags before and after the unformatted shortcodes, then runs do_shortcode.

**EDIT**

The solution above can also cause some HTML errors. Best practice would be to remove wpautop filter, and then add a shortcode which calls wpautop around content. Like this:

```
add_shortcode('text', function($attributes, $content = null)
{

    // Output
    return do_shortcode(wpautop($content));

});
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're removing/adding the default filters in the first place. I tried a mocked-up version of your shortcode without messing with filters and it outputted fine, with no additional/extraneous `<p>`'s...

Comment: Inside a shortcode? By default shortcodes are wrapped in a <p> tag. shortcode_unautop was suppose to remove the paragraphs again, but it messed with my content inside the shortcode.

Comment: You're running this shortcode inside another shortcode? If so it'd be useful if you could update your question to show the situation more fully. I'm interested in trying to get `wpautop()` fixed for 4.5 (or whenever) and the more case studies the better - see also https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34722 and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215727/why-does-wp-not-like-my-a-container.

Comment: No. Its a regular shortcode within the_content(). If i use the default filter setup, i get paragraph tags around everything. * Note to my solution: This removes p tags from ANY shortcode, so inline elements in shortcodes are not wrapped in P tags which could some in handy.

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce that with the default filter setup. What your filter does is a less targeted (ie will not only affect shortcodes) version of what `shortcode_unautop()` does (except that that doesn't deal with shortcodes within shortcodes). Oh well...

Comment: If I could upvote more than once, I would. I have been searching for a fix for shortcode_unautop() for, what seems like, forever!

Comment: I would not do this to my code, seems super shady to mess arround with the default priorities for such crucial core WP filters other plugins and themes expect to be where they are by default. This may sure fix this issue bit it looks just like horrible solution to me.

Answer (score 2):

The above solution doesn't work if you're using Advanced Custom Fields. When using ACF, the following code does work:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'acf_the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 99);
add_filter( 'acf_the_content', 'wpautop' , 100);
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop',110 );
add_filter( 'acf_the_content', 'shortcode_unautop',111 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try removing all the newlines from the output itself, since this is what is ultimately being messed with...

```
$output .= '<div ' . implode(' ', $html_attributes) . '>';
$output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
$output .= '<div ' . implode(' ', $html_attributes_inner) . '>';
$output .= $logo;
```

...and so forth. If the newlines are gone maybe wpautop will leave the shortcode output alone.

otherwise, since it is a very specific and misformatted string output, you could always fix for it after the fact:

```
add_filter('the_content','shortcode_fix',110);
function shortcode_fix($content) {
    return str_replace('<p></a></div>','</a></div>',$content);
}
```

....

Comment: Isn't that what my str_replace function does?

Comment: Righto, didn't get that to begin with... just seemed really strange that it is adding paragraphs when there are no new lines...